# Why does Apple TV show screensaver when playing video?

Tags: appletv, screensaver, hulu, netflix

On occasion, our 3rd Gen ATV will display the screensaver while playing video. Once it starts doing this, the only way to get it to stop is by restarting.  I love my ATV, but this is quite a distraction.

So far, I've noticed that this occurs with both Hulu and Netflix.  The reports I've seen say that a reboot solved the issue with no follow-ups.  For me, that fix is temporary.  A few days later, the problem is back again.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

That is very unusual behavior and should not be happening. Try restoring the firmware of the ATV by plugging it into a computer, opening iTunes, and selecting Restore.

Note you will have to re-enter all of your passwords into the ATV afterwards.

Comment: Great idea.  I'll give that a shot and report back.